# Opening & Closing HTML tags with multiple logic Loops inbetween

Tags: php, html, loops

I'm trying to loop and display my category properly basically

1) I need to call the `Div`, `H3` & `UL` if it's depth is 1 (Category)

2) If depth equals 2 (Sub category) I push it in `<li>`

3) The problem is, if i detect depth 1 and display the first `Div`, I don't know how to call `</div>` the ending tag to close if after the depth 2 statement is complete.

```
<div class="col-md-4 header-navigation-col">
     <h4>Category's Name</h4>
     <ul>
        <li><a>Sub Category</a></li>
        <li><a>Sub Category</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

My code

```
@foreach($catWomen->getDescendants() as $descendant)
    <?php if($descendant->depth == 1){
            echo '<div class="col-md-4 header-navigation-col">';
            echo '<h4>Category Name</h4>';
        }elseif($descendant->depth == 2){
            echo '<li><a>Sub Category</a></li>';
        }
    ?>
@endforeach
```

How do I close my first `Div`?

Comment: If I understand it right, your `getDescendants` call returns an array of objects all which include a `depth` property. Objects either have a depth of 1 or 2 and there could be multiple of both. If you have something like: `[ 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2 ]`, where those numbers are just the depth values, you know for certain that all the '2's that directly follow a '1' are for that specific descendant? I bring this up as the actual model structure you have seems a little strange.

Comment: Check the the title tag: h3 or h4? Example and code have different tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$close_div = "";
@foreach($catWomen->getDescendants() as $descendant)
    <?php 
        if($descendant->depth == 1){
            echo($close_div);// first time it is empty string, then always is "</div>"
            $close_div = "</div>";
            echo '<div class="col-md-4 header-navigation-col">';
            echo '<h4>Category Name</h4>';
        }elseif($descendant->depth == 2){
            echo '<li><a>Sub Category</a></li>';
        }
    ?>
@endforeach
```